# What is difference among "come" "come up" "come over" and "come around"?

Tags: difference, idioms

Would anyone explain the differences among the followings phrases, please?

1. "come" to your place
2. "come up" your place
3. "come over" to your place
4. "come around" to your place

I'm now personally designing a VERY CASUAL leaflet for customers in order to spread my business.  I am a (Japanese) professional photographer (living in Japan), and will visit customers places (not only their home/houses but also schools, kindergartens, stadiums, grounds, halls, dog-runs, etc) in order to take photos of their child(ren) or pet(s).

Then, I would like to use one of the above word/idioms on my leaflet saying "If the calculations are correct, when we come (up) to your place, you're gonna see many wonderful xxxx ....." by modifying Dr Emmett Brown's line from *Back to the Future*.

This sentence will be shown with quite quite small letters, only 5 points, on my leaflet.  Therefore it would not need to have any advertising effect at all.  Yes, it is just like a decoration on its design.

Comment: Please don't use 'gonna' on any official leaflet. Apart from its use in the description of dialog, it is a real sign of illiteracy.  The phrase is 'going to'.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK: "Going to" was once considered less than literate as well. Don't tell me you actually say "going to" instead of "gonna" - do you? I'm pretty sure even Queen Elizabeth says "Oi!" (rather than "Hey, you!"), and she's pretty literate, or so they tell me.

Comment: @Ricky Of course, he doesn't *say* "going to," but this is a business leaflet, where "gonna" should be spelled "going to."

Comment: The "calculations" quote is "If my calculations are correct, when this baby hits 88 miles per hour... you're gonna see some serious shit."  Please give the context of your quote for "come up."

Comment: @deadrat: Do you mean that "Hop-o-My-Thumb" should be spelled "Hop On My Thumb" on business leaflets? And "objet d'art" should be spelled "Art Object and Down with the French"?

Comment: I do appreciate and thank you 2 : chasly from UK-san and Ricky-san for your quick and kind answers.  But I'd like you 2 not to worry about MY usage of "gonna", please.  I, even an naive Japanese, already know that "gonna" is definitely not suitable in official leaflets.  However why I still stay on that rude wording is that I'd just like to make a fun copy of Doc's world famous lines.  So, would you forget about "gonna", and could you explain the differences of "come"s", please???  Thank you.

Comment: @Ricky No, it should be spelled, "Here, hop on this."

Comment: Just say "I {will/can} come to your home."  It doesn't matter whether you have to go over, up, down, around, under or through (literally or idiomatically); it only matters that you will get to their home somehow.

Comment: Basically, the phrases all mean the same thing, with selection largely dependent on the physical realities.  "Come up to your place" would be used for an apartment on an upper floor of a building, "come over" is a bit more generic, but has the sense of traveling across a street, city, bridge, etc.  "Come around" isn't so much about physical layout as timing -- it implies being flexible about when the visit may occur.  But all these implications are quite vague.

Comment: First of all, I do appreciate all of you guys, oops, sorry, not guys but gentlemen, posting the above comments.   I really thank you for your kind advices which are all very precious to me as an English learner.   So, let me reply back to every comment when I get home tonight.

Answer (score 5):

All those expressions mean largely the same thing, with a few very subtle differences (connotations):

**Please come over to my place tomorrow night.**

This means "When you're someplace else tonight, standing or sitting, working or drinking, I would like you to start moving in the direction of my place; cover the distance that separates you from my place by car, by train, or on foot, I don't care. I'd like to see you. You're officially invited."

**Please come by my place tomorrow.**

This means "When you're on your way to wherever you need to be, by train, by car, or on foot, make a stop at my door, there's a good boy. Don't forget to ring the bell. I'll be home."

**Please come up to my place tonight.**

This means "When you're done with whatever you're doing today and/or tonight, just remember me and get to my place. It's north (or uphill) from wherever you expect to be at that point; you can't miss it. Bring a bottle of chardonnay, I'll make the sushi. Or would you prefer Italian? I like Italian. I think you like it too. Don't bring your wife or mistress, that would be uncouth. Come by yourself."

**Come around my place tonight.**

This means "Very casually, as if by accident, please end up standing in front of my door tonight. Don't forget to ring the bell. Bring a bottle of chardonnay only if you really mean it."

Something like that.

Comment: 144252:  As a new user to ELU who says that his English is poor, I'd like to explain that Ricky's answer is very, very funny.  Adorably funny.  I haven't stopped laughing since I read it.  If you don't understand why it's so amusing, it would be best not to take the answer too literally.

Comment: How could it hurt him, @deadrat-san? Oh, you mean the Italian thing. Well, French cuisine is labor-intensive and, frankly, you can't whip up a decent French snack just like that, on the spur of the moment, not without cheating a little. Italian, on the other hand, is ridiculously simple: cook anything at all, then drown it in tomato sauce, add some spaghetti, and - voila! Plus, chardonnay doesn't really go with French food, whilst pretty much anything can go with Italian. Even Belgian beer.

Comment: Ha ha ha ha ha ha ha!  Er, meh.  Will you be here all week?  Because I really can't get enough of this.  But to answer your question, you're talking to a low-rep, brand-new user who tells you his English is poor.  Humor is a hard thing to understand in a language you're just learning, probably even harder than understanding idiom.  You're perpetrating a minor cruelty.  You should probably stop doing that.

Comment: Probably ... Many people don't understand humor in any language, and some get resentful when they hear it. ... I don't like hurting people except for sport. ... The Germans on the adjacent forum put my question on hold the other day. I was looking for an ancient Germanic name from the days of the Roman Empire for a character in my play. I asked them to think of one that could be easily Latinized and whose diminutive would sound cute. Was that a crime? When they put it on hold, I wrote "Thanks, guys, you've been really helpful." They deleted the question. Useless cretins.

Comment: @Ricky: yeah, 'cause we all know hurting people is OK when done for sport...?

Comment: Do you guys still have libraries in California? If not, try Kindle. Look for "Pudd'nhead Wilson" by Mark Twain. Budda bing, budda boom. As Lenin used to say. ... Sheesh.

Comment: You can't whip up a decent French snack on the spur of the moment? I suppose you've never had the most common French snack of them all: a baguette smeared with butter or paté.

Comment: That would be cheating. It takes at least a day to make a proper baguette, and a lot longer to make pate. Spaghetti from scratch: 1 hour. Rookies ...

Comment: @Ricky : Ricky-san, the first of all, I'd like to say "I thank you so much!" and also like to express my sincere appreciation to you! You ARE the only one who did kindly explain the differences among those idioms. That's what I have really wanted to know, sir!!!

Comment: @Ricky : Ricky-san, let me tell you one thing about our English education in Japan.  Almost everyone of Japanese have taken English classes for at least 6 years at school : 3 yrs @ junior high & another 3 yrs @ high school.   1 lesson a day everyday times 6 years!   However the the lesson are mainly occupied by reading and writing, not by conversation when I was a student.  As to words, we learned more difficult words than simple idioms.   (Sorry that I forgot all that difficult ones at all.  lol.)  That's why it's so difficult for us to understand the subtle differences in idioms.

Comment: @Ricky : Ricky-san, please do Not take like I am complaining about our education, but I'd just like to tell it's little bit hard to understand each meaning of the idioms formed with verb + adverb phrases.   Adverbs of manner you called???   Those are some tough stuff, I think.  So, I hadn't asked today's questions to anyone yet.

Comment: @Ricky : Ricky-san, therefore I really thank YOU so much for your kind explanation in details.    And......Yes, I can catch YOUR humor hopefully most of all, and am able to see OTHERS' foolish irony.   So, Ricky-san, please do not worry, I did Not get hurt any!  Not at all!   I rather feel so sorry to them...  yeah, in any places of world, in the Eastern or Western,  in the past and in the present, there they are!!!   I don't care what they say to me, I just care and pay all my attention to whoever gives me a valuable information.

Comment: @Ricky : Ricky-san, oh, you like Italian!   So do I!!!  I love pizza, especially thin ones, not like California's thick bread-alike ones.   I also like spagetties, too.   How about you?  And you like Sushi, too???   If you have a chance to come to Japan, please come OVER to my place then, I get you nice Sushi and Sake (Japanese rice wine).   My town, Utsunomiya, is located neighboring NIKKO, one of the World Heritages, you should come visit!!!  ^ ^

Answer (score 1):

Some of those phrasings have idiomatic meanings.  In a business context, it's best to just say "I {will/can} come to your home."

It doesn't matter whether you have to go over, up, down, around, under or through (literally or idiomatically); it only matters that you will get to their home somehow.