# Can I use the phrasal verb "come over" to ask someone to come to my home who lives in another city?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Can I use the phrasal verb *come over* to ask someone to come to my home who lives in another city? For example:

> My friend lives in York. I sometimes ask him to **come over**.

Would it be more natural to say any of the following?

> I sometimes ask my friend to **come to me**.
>
> I sometimes ask my friend to **come to my home**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is difference among "come" "come up" "come over" and "come around"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/72307/what-is-difference-among-come-come-up-come-over-and-come-around)

Comment: Not really! It's not clear if I can say "come over" to somebody  on its own not mentioning the place especially when the person I want to come over and they live in another city.

Comment: If you read Ricky's answer to the earlier question carefully, you should be able to see the implication that *to come **over*** is often subtly different to *come **by***. By further implication, you wouldn't normally use the ***by*** version when addressing someone in another city (unless they were coming ***to*** the general area of your city anyway, and you were suggesting they make a slight "detour" specifically to pay you a visit). As regards *come to **me / my home***, I guess much depends on which of those two you think is more important! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, your question is actually about whether there is a distance limit to when the verb "come over" can be used.

It is perfectly grammatically correct, and the meaning is certainly clear, but I think you are right that using the verb "come over" when somebody is very far away (like another city) sounds a bit strange.  I think this is because "come over" generally implies that the activity of coming to your location is something that somebody can do fairly casually, which means it's something that should not take too long or be really complicated (or require planning, etc).  Since going from one city to another is usually something that takes some planning and work, it's not really a casual thing.

So, for example, this sounds a bit strange:

> My friend lives in York. I sometimes ask him to come over.

but on the other hand, this is perfectly natural:

> My friend lives in York. I sometimes ask him to come over when he's visiting my city.

because there, the implication is that, since he's already visiting your city, he's in the area, and "coming over" isn't that much of an extra thing to do in that case.

However, in terms of how to better phrase your original sentence, really all the forms of "come" you mention have some sense of casualness, so probably aren't entirely appropriate.  I think most people would instead say something like:

> My friend lives in York. I sometimes ask him to visit me.

or

> My friend lives in York. I sometimes ask him to visit me at my home.

Here, "visit" usually implies a bit more of a deliberate action, and thus is perfectly appropriate even when travelling a long way (planning a trip, etc).